# Python - Display Seaborn KDE Plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn, kernel-density

I want to display Seaborn KDE Plot but I could'nt get to display it with a normal `show` method. How shall I do it?

```
import numpy as np 
from scipy.fftpack import dct
import seaborn 

sample1 = dct(np.random.rand(100))
sample2 = dct(np.random.rand(30))
seaborn.kdeplot(sample1, color="r")
seaborn.kdeplot(sample2, color="b")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```py
import numpy as np 
from scipy.fftpack import dct
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()

sample1 = dct(np.random.rand(100))
sample2 = dct(np.random.rand(30))
sns.kdeplot(sample1, color="r")
sns.kdeplot(sample2, color="b")
plt.show()
```

**Output**
[image]